# Symmetric multi processing

Tags: 12.04

In a symmetric multiprocessing (SMP) environment, multiple processors share other hardware resources, such as memory or storage. They have a single operating system. How to install or configure symmetric multiprocessing in Linux.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Multiprocessor support is activated by default in the 12.04 amd64 kernel:

> Multiprocessor support — also called “symmetric multiprocessing” or SMP — is available for this architecture. The standard Ubuntu 12.04 kernel image has been compiled with SMP-alternatives support. This means that the kernel will detect the number of processors (or processor cores) and will automatically deactivate SMP on uniprocessor systems. <sup>[Ubuntu 12.04 Supported Hardware](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/hardware-supported.html)</sup>

Other than stated in the [hardware specs](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/hardware-supported.html) the 32-bit kernel on Ubuntu should be compiled with SMP support too. In case you have another kernel you may however have to [manually compile the kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/kernel-baking.html) to support SMP.

Comment: 32 bit kernel has SMP enabled - it's in the kernel source common configs: debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu - CONFIG_SMP=y

Comment: Thanks @ColinIanKing - then it may be that the entry from Ubuntu hardware specs is dated?  It says *"The 486 flavour of the Ubuntu kernel image packages for Intel x86 is not compiled with SMP support. "*

Answer (score 2):

Follow this [tutorial](http://folding.stanford.edu/English/LinSMPGuide)"Linux SMP Client Installation Guide" to know how

Comment: Please include information from the link as if the linked site were to go down, your answer would not help future users wishing to use SMP.

Comment: .yeah sure i've got your  point of view but the problem  the answer is long.Thanks

Comment: The community frowns upon link-only answers, even if it is long. Also, the link is specific to a specific Folding@Home project, and not general SMP. can you find a link that is not project-specific?

Comment: @maythux You're right that you should not copy a copyrighted work, word-for-word, that is long--that would probably violate the copyright, unless you have permission or it's licensed compatibly with [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). But you can provide some information nonetheless. Please see [this policy and community consensus about link-only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259), for details.